# How to order a list by two conditions

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I'm a little stuck... I have ArrayList of HashTable with this structure:

```
DataClasses1DataContext csdx = new DataClasses1DataContext();

IQueryable<dataType> dtList = csdx.datatypes.Where(dd => !dd.data_approve_date.Equals(null)).OrderBy(dd => dd.data_sign_date);


        dtList = dtList.Where(dt => dt.data_end <= qEnd || dt.data_sign_date <= qEnd);

        ArrayList dtList = new ArrayList();
        Hashtable dtElement = new Hashtable();  

        foreach (dataType dtt in dtList.ToList())
             {
              dtElement["signdate"] = dtt.data_sign_date.Date;
              dtElement["end"] = dtt.data_end;
              dtElement["sum"] = dtt.data_sum;

              dtList.Add(dtElement);
        }
```

qEnd is the end of the closed quarter of the year (2014-03-31)
The datas are like these coming from the Linq query:

signdate: 2013-10-05,
end: 2014-02-15,
sum: 65000

signdate: 2014-01-21,
end: 2016-01-21,
sum: 45000

signdate: 2014-03-24,
end: 2015-06-24,
sum: 95000

I have to order them by signdate AND end in the actual (closed) year quarter. So the order of the above list would be this:

signdate: 2014-01-21,
end: 2016-01-21,
sum: 45000

signdate: 2013-10-05,
end: 2014-02-15,
sum: 65000

signdate: 2014-03-24,
end: 2015-06-24,
sum: 95000

As you can see I query them by sign_date, but this list isn't sorted be the second date as well. The end is only relevant when it's in the actual quarter range.

How can I perform this task?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use System.Collection classes like ArrayList, use generics - System.Collection.Generic.List. Then it's as simple as list.OrderBy(a=>a.prop1).OrderBy(b=>b.prop2)

Comment: Great :) But how can I access the "signdate" and "end" items in the orderBy? list.OrderBy(o => o.???)

Comment: The code sample is a bit unclear (I'm guessing bondElement is actually dtElement in the sample), but it seems that your big problem is that you are using non-generic collections. You should replace the Hashtable with a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, T> where T is your type. But I'd question the wisdom of using a key/value pair to collect the values in the foreach loop, you would be better to create a new type with 3 properties IMO if that is possible.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the name problem. I'm trying with this now: dtList.OrderBy(o => o["signdate"]).OrderBy(o => o["end"]); Well, I'm using hashtable, because not all three properties have the same data type. (two DataTimes and one double)

Comment: This is why you should use a class rather than a Hashtable and create  a list of instances of that class (or use a new { ... }) for each iteration, adding the objects to a list.You also have a bug in you code, you are constantly updating the same elements in the hashtable (since you are using the same instance for each iteration), so all Hashtables in the list will have the same values at present.